# Eclipselink and Postgresql batch writing

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, eclipselink, jpa-2.1

I have been working on a BulkSMS solution for one of my customers, and I have decided to use JPA (Eclipselink) as an ORM and the underlying database is PostgreSQL 9.5.1.

My problem issue is that whenever I send a request with 65,000  records to be persisted it takes around 27 seconds to complete the operation. I decided to implement sequence pooling, sequence preallocation =1000, and batch writing, however this only managed to remove 15 seconds from the operation.

After investigating the database logs I noticed that the same queries are being called before and after applying the optimization.

Here is my optimized persistance.xml:

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="com.kw.ktt.sms.server" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>SMSDB</jta-data-source>
     <non-jta-data-source>sequence</non-jta-data-source> 
    <class>com.kw.ktt.sms.server.core.TestClass</class>
    <class>com.kw.ktt.sms.server.jpa.Customer</class>
    <class>com.kw.ktt.sms.server.jpa.SMSAccount</class>
    <class>com.kw.ktt.sms.server.jpa.SMSTransaction</class>
    <class>com.kw.ktt.sms.server.jpa.ContactGroup</class>
    <class>com.kw.ktt.sms.server.jpa.PhoneNumber</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.application-location" value="/Users/mousaalsulaimi/Desktop"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.connection" value="true"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC" /> 
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size" value="1000"/> 
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.sequence-connection-pool"  value="true" />
        <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.sequence.nonJtaDataSource" value="sequence"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.sequence.intial" value="1000" /> 
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

As mentioned above I'm using a JTA connection pool for persistence (called SMSDB) and non JTA connection for sequencing (called sequence)  each with a different DB user in order to easily track the connection the DB log.

Logs for the unoptimized connection [are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkJ0Z.png) - this is a sample of 10 records only.

The logs for the optimized connection [are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo2BL.png)  - this is a sample of 10 records only.

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong and why both persistence setting produce the same queries even though there is a actual improvement of 15 seconds.

One more thing , I have set the sequence preallocation to 1000 in the Entitiy's source code and judging from the database logs sequencing is working as expected and is picking up the correct increment value . What I'm concerned with is the batch writing and I fear that it is not set up correctly in the persistence.xml

**Update**

I have enables the logging in eclipse link as advised by Chris , 
 here is the eclipseLink logs produced when using the optimized persistence.xml

```
2016-02-27T23:59:28.307+0300|Fine: SELECT CUSTOMERID, CIVILIDNUMBER, CREATEDATE, CREATEDBY, EMAIL, FULLNAME, ISACTIVE, ISADMIN, MALE, PASSWORD, PERSONAL, PHONENUMBER, STATUS, USERNAME, ACCOUNT_SMSACCOUNTID FROM CUSTOMER WHERE (CUSTOMERID = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.310+0300|Fine: SELECT SMSACCOUNTID, OOOREDOOO_BALANCE, VIVA_BALANCE, ZAIN_BALANCE FROM SMSACCOUNT WHERE (SMSACCOUNTID = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.312+0300|Fine: select nextval('SEQ_GEN_SEQUENCE')
2016-02-27T23:59:28.327+0300|Fine: select nextval('number_seq')
2016-02-27T23:59:28.331+0300|Info: this is the id 1
2016-02-27T23:59:28.332+0300|Fine: INSERT INTO SMSACCOUNT (SMSACCOUNTID, OOOREDOOO_BALANCE, VIVA_BALANCE, ZAIN_BALANCE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [4 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.335+0300|Fine: INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUSTOMERID, CIVILIDNUMBER, CREATEDATE, CREATEDBY, EMAIL, FULLNAME, ISACTIVE, ISADMIN, MALE, PASSWORD, PERSONAL, PHONENUMBER, STATUS, USERNAME, ACCOUNT_SMSACCOUNTID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [15 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.337+0300|Fine: INSERT INTO CONTACTGROUP (GROUPID, CREATEBY, CREATEDATE, GROUPDESCRIPTION, GROUPNAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [5 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.339+0300|Fine: INSERT INTO PHONENUMBER (NUMBERID, OPERATOR, PHONENUMBER) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
2016-02-27T23:59:28.339+0300|Fine: bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.339+0300|Fine: bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.339+0300|Fine: bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.339+0300|Fine: bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.339+0300|Fine: bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.339+0300|Fine: bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.339+0300|Fine: bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.340+0300|Fine: bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.340+0300|Fine: bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.340+0300|Fine: bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.342+0300|Fine: UPDATE CONTACTGROUP SET customerID = ? WHERE (GROUPID = ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.343+0300|Fine: UPDATE PHONENUMBER SET groupId = ? WHERE (NUMBERID = ?)
2016-02-27T23:59:28.344+0300|Fine: bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.344+0300|Fine: bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.344+0300|Fine: bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.344+0300|Fine: bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.344+0300|Fine: bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.344+0300|Fine: bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.344+0300|Fine: bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.344+0300|Fine: bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.344+0300|Fine: bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-27T23:59:28.344+0300|Fine: bind => [2 parameters bound]
```

and below the eclipse link logs produced when using the original persistence.xml

```
2016-02-28T08:56:25.440+0300|Fine: SELECT CUSTOMERID, CIVILIDNUMBER, CREATEDATE, CREATEDBY, EMAIL, FULLNAME, ISACTIVE, ISADMIN, MALE, PASSWORD, PERSONAL, PHONENUMBER, STATUS, USERNAME, ACCOUNT_SMSACCOUNTID FROM CUSTOMER WHERE (CUSTOMERID = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.443+0300|Fine: SELECT SMSACCOUNTID, OOOREDOOO_BALANCE, VIVA_BALANCE, ZAIN_BALANCE FROM SMSACCOUNT WHERE (SMSACCOUNTID = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.445+0300|Fine: select nextval('SEQ_GEN_SEQUENCE')
2016-02-28T08:56:25.447+0300|Fine: select nextval('number_seq')
2016-02-28T08:56:25.449+0300|Info: this is the id 1
2016-02-28T08:56:25.450+0300|Fine: INSERT INTO SMSACCOUNT (SMSACCOUNTID, OOOREDOOO_BALANCE, VIVA_BALANCE, ZAIN_BALANCE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [4 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.451+0300|Fine: INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUSTOMERID, CIVILIDNUMBER, CREATEDATE, CREATEDBY, EMAIL, FULLNAME, ISACTIVE, ISADMIN, MALE, PASSWORD, PERSONAL, PHONENUMBER, STATUS, USERNAME, ACCOUNT_SMSACCOUNTID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [15 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.452+0300|Fine: INSERT INTO CONTACTGROUP (GROUPID, CREATEBY, CREATEDATE, GROUPDESCRIPTION, GROUPNAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [5 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.452+0300|Fine: INSERT INTO PHONENUMBER (NUMBERID, OPERATOR, PHONENUMBER) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.453+0300|Fine: INSERT INTO PHONENUMBER (NUMBERID, OPERATOR, PHONENUMBER) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.453+0300|Fine: INSERT INTO PHONENUMBER (NUMBERID, OPERATOR, PHONENUMBER) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.454+0300|Fine: INSERT INTO PHONENUMBER (NUMBERID, OPERATOR, PHONENUMBER) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.454+0300|Fine: INSERT INTO PHONENUMBER (NUMBERID, OPERATOR, PHONENUMBER) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.454+0300|Fine: INSERT INTO PHONENUMBER (NUMBERID, OPERATOR, PHONENUMBER) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.455+0300|Fine: INSERT INTO PHONENUMBER (NUMBERID, OPERATOR, PHONENUMBER) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.455+0300|Fine: INSERT INTO PHONENUMBER (NUMBERID, OPERATOR, PHONENUMBER) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.455+0300|Fine: INSERT INTO PHONENUMBER (NUMBERID, OPERATOR, PHONENUMBER) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.456+0300|Fine: INSERT INTO PHONENUMBER (NUMBERID, OPERATOR, PHONENUMBER) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.456+0300|Fine: UPDATE CONTACTGROUP SET customerID = ? WHERE (GROUPID = ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.457+0300|Fine: UPDATE PHONENUMBER SET groupId = ? WHERE (NUMBERID = ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.457+0300|Fine: UPDATE PHONENUMBER SET groupId = ? WHERE (NUMBERID = ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.458+0300|Fine: UPDATE PHONENUMBER SET groupId = ? WHERE (NUMBERID = ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.458+0300|Fine: UPDATE PHONENUMBER SET groupId = ? WHERE (NUMBERID = ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.459+0300|Fine: UPDATE PHONENUMBER SET groupId = ? WHERE (NUMBERID = ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.459+0300|Fine: UPDATE PHONENUMBER SET groupId = ? WHERE (NUMBERID = ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.460+0300|Fine: UPDATE PHONENUMBER SET groupId = ? WHERE (NUMBERID = ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.460+0300|Fine: UPDATE PHONENUMBER SET groupId = ? WHERE (NUMBERID = ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.460+0300|Fine: UPDATE PHONENUMBER SET groupId = ? WHERE (NUMBERID = ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
2016-02-28T08:56:25.461+0300|Fine: UPDATE PHONENUMBER SET groupId = ? WHERE (NUMBERID = ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
```

obviously there is a big difference between the queries produced when using the optimized persistence.xml and the original persistence.xml .

Comment: Looks like the ContactGroup update is forcing the Phonenumber batch statement to be executed earlier then I would expect.  You might look into the mapping on this to determine why EclipseLink thinks it must execute the ContactGroup statement before it can continue with Phonenumbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on EclipseLink's SQL logging and you should see a difference in how the statements are prepared and processed in JDBC, which should show why there is a 15 second difference.

I'm not familiar with the eclipselink.connection-pool.sequence.intial property - What you should likely be using is the [allocationSize](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/persistence/javadoc-1_0-fr/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html) configuration within your sequence generator itself to allow obtaining 1000 sequences at a time.

If it is not set, batch writing will cut down the number of insert statements, but you will still see a large number of statements to obtain sequence numbers, but over different connections - sequencing is using its own connection pool.

Comment: I might have not mentioned this but I have already set the allocation size to 1000 , this is defined in the Entitiy's source code . I do not this that the sequencing is the issue since the attached logs show that eclipse link is correctly requesting the sequence values , for example for 65000 records eclipse link actually calls the sequence.nextVal 60 times only , which means the preallocation is working fine .  As for eclipselink.connection-pool.sequence .intial , I think that this is being ignored by eclipslink since the I'm using an external connection pool (glassfish )

Comment: My concern is that batch writing is not working or not set up correctly in the persistance .xml , any ways I will turn on jdbc logging as you have indicated as check the results , I was not aware of this feature. Thank you very much Chris.

Comment: Thank You Very Much  Chris the eclipselink logs helped alot , but I expected that the optimization is done on the Database level not on the ORM level , the Database logs looks the same .